# How to select and change the percentage value in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning web developing and I just found this Liquid Bubble Progress Bar code to practice.

Here it is: https://codepen.io/junebug12851/pen/mJZNqN

My problem is I can't figure out **how the javascript defines the Percentage value?**

I've tried to define the **percentage value** in code without any success:

```
var val = $(this).val(89);
```

I just want to get rid of that percentage text input and define the percentage value in code using a JS variable.

JS:

```
var colorInc = 100 / 3;

$(function()
{
  $("#percent-box").click(function()
  {
    $(this).select();
  });

  $("#percent-box").keyup(function()
  {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val != ""
      && !isNaN(val)
      && val <= 100
      && val >= 0)
    {
      console.log(val);

      var valOrig = val;
      val = 100 - val;

      if(valOrig == 0)
      {
        $("#percent-box").val(0);
        $(".progress .percent").text(0 + "%");
      }
      else $(".progress .percent").text(valOrig + "%");

      $(".progress").parent().removeClass();
      $(".progress .water").css("top", val + "%");

      if(valOrig < colorInc * 1)
        $(".progress").parent().addClass("red");
      else if(valOrig < colorInc * 2)
        $(".progress").parent().addClass("orange");
      else
        $(".progress").parent().addClass("green");
    }
    else
    {
      $(".progress").parent().removeClass();
      $(".progress").parent().addClass("green");
      $(".progress .water").css("top", 100 - 67 + "%");
      $(".progress .percent").text(67 + "%");
      $("#percent-box").val("");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please don't link to code on 3rd party sites. Insert code right into your question as a code snippet.

Comment: Have you looked into $("#percent-box").keyup(function(){}); ?? This is the code that executes when you change the value in the example you've given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$(".progress .percent").text(20 + "%");
```

Animation

```
$(".progress .water").css("top", 20 + "%");
```

Comment: May I ask you please to update your codepen! I can't make it work... Do you have the animations between 67 to 20 %?

Comment: Instead of "20" I'm creating a variable called percentVar ... and tring to change the numbers frome 67 to 20 but there is no animations...:(

Comment: I've commented out the relevant part https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GLQQZr